# JavaScript big integer square root

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigint

This concerns the new JavaScript BigInt type, as supported in Chrome and Node v10.4

Both the following lines throw an error:

```
Math.sqrt(9n)
Math.sqrt(BigInt(9))
```

Error is:

> Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number

How do I get the square root of a BigInt in JavaScript? TIA

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From here: https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/javascript-bigint.html

```
function sqrt(value) {
    if (value < 0n) {
        throw 'square root of negative numbers is not supported'
    }

    if (value < 2n) {
        return value;
    }

    function newtonIteration(n, x0) {
        const x1 = ((n / x0) + x0) >> 1n;
        if (x0 === x1 || x0 === (x1 - 1n)) {
            return x0;
        }
        return newtonIteration(n, x1);
    }

    return newtonIteration(value, 1n);
}

sqrt(BigInt(9))
```

Comment: For initial guess (`1n` is passed to the first call of `newtonIteration`) it could be better to use something like `const guess = 1n + (sqrt(value >> BigInt(Math.floor(bitLength(value) / 2))) << BigInt(Math.floor(bitLength(value) / 4)));`, where `bitLength` is defined as `function bitLength(n) { return n.toString(16).length * 4; }`. This could make it faster for very big integers.

Comment: This only works for whole number square roots, unfortunately.

Comment: Just an fyi, passing in `4n` seems to give `1n`, not `2n` as expected. Seems the iteration bias is causing this, i.e., the `x0 === (x1 - 1n)`. This appears to be the only erroneous case; so perhaps making an additional special case for it would suffice.

Comment: Certain initial guesses, such as what @4esn0k mentioned, you need to `return x1` instead of `return x0`, with the caveat that sqrt (N^2 - 1) returns N.

Answer (score 3):

## General case: n-th root

Here is more general solution for [n-th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm)

```js
/**
 * Calculate n-th root of val
 * Parameters:
 * k: is n-th (default sqare root)
 * limit: is maximum number of iterations (default: -1 no limit)
 */
function rootNth(val, k=2n, limit=-1) {
    let o = 0n; // old approx value
    let x = val;
    
    while(x**k!==k && x!==o && --limit) {
      o=x;
      x = ((k-1n)*x + val/x**(k-1n))/k;
      if(limit<0 && (x-o)**2n == 1n) break;
    }
    
    if ((val-(x-1n)**k)**2n < (val-x**k)**2n) x=x-1n;
    if ((val-(x+1n)**k)**2n < (val-x**k)**2n) x=x+1n;
    return x;
}

let v = 1000000n;
console.log(`root^3 form ${v} = ${rootNth(v,3n)}` );
```

Comment: this function return a wrong result if it do more than `limit` iterations. It should better throw an error.

Comment: The problem noted by @Yukulélé occurs even for small values of `value` because `o` and `x` oscillate between `R` and `R+1`, where `R` is the correct root, when `value` is 1 less than a perfect square. For such numbers, the returned value will be 1 larger than the correct root 50% of the time. I added `if(x>o) return o;` as the third line in the while loop to fix this issue. For legit cases where the limit is exceeded. an error would still be appropriate. I am not sure that this solution is correct, though, as I don't understand the algorithm.

Comment: @JaredBrandt - can you give some examples / test cases? (link to algorithm is in answer)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Thanks, I missed the link! I studied it and agree it is implemented correctly, but for some reason it doesn't behave with integers, and I haven't studied it enough to know why. I copied the code directly into a fiddle, changed the cube root to square root, the radicand to (5^2-1), and added a console.log() in the while loop. You can see it oscillates between 4 and 5, but incorrectly settles on 5. Changing the radicand to (3^2-1) oscillates between 2 and 3, and correctly settles on 2. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cf2y84nr/

Comment: @JaredBrandt I modify answer. Now I assume that algorithm gives value which can be smaller or greater than right value by 1. So I test two cases: when x-1 is better than x, and if x+1 is better than x - and choose better solution as x. (instead using `Math.abs` i compare squares `**2n`). I also add automagical calculation of limit (which is also speed optimisation)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I do believe this has become unnecessarily complicated. May I have your blessing to edit the answer?

Comment: @JaredBrandt if you can simplify - feel free to do it

Answer (score 3):

There is an npm library [bigint-isqrt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-isqrt), seem to work ok. It returns the floor value if there is no integer root.

```
const sqrt = require('bigint-isqrt');
> sqrt(1023n);
31n
> sqrt(1024n);
32n
```

<sub>Though it's still a mystery for me how magic numbers like `value < 16n` and `1n << 52n` in it's implementation help finding a square root. Judging from a [PR](https://github.com/Aisse-258/bigint-isqrt/pull/1) it's some sort of an approximation heuristic, I wonder whether it's more efficient than algorithms in other answers...</sub>

Comment: From a test on my Firefox browser, this is 10 times faster for 50 digits and is 50 times faster for 500. Perfect for my use case!